# Is it necessary to use HTTPS between web server and API server?

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, https, tls1.2

I have an web server which render HTML webpage to user and recieve request from front-end.

Then I also have a Node.js web app that recieve API request from web server and response it.

Node.js web app stores very important contents so I want keep it secure.

The flow of data is like below.

User <-> Web server <-> Node App

So I'm planning setup TLS on my web server so user's web browser and server will communicate under HTTPS.

But the case of Node App, I cannot install SSL Certification because I cannot connect SSH with this app.

Web server has a secure authentication key for connect with Node App and Only this web server is connecting with Node App.

In this case, is it necessary to use HTTPS between Web server and Node app?

Comment: So is this a server->to->server request? Are they in the same network? Do you control that network? If you answered 'no' to any of these questions, you probably need SSL.

Comment: @Evert Hi Evert. It's in same network and controlled by Web hosting company. But when call API, it uses external IP so I think the packet will not move in only internal network. Thanks for your answer.